# How do I select only one of two identical objects, on top of each, in edge or edit mode?

Tags: objects, transforms, edges, selection-tools, wireframe

Ok, so as shown below, I have these two cubes, and I'm in edge mode. What I'm trying to do is just select the entire Cube .001 so I can use the Alt + S scale tool to scale it down, while keeping it inside the other cube. I don't know how to select the Cube .001 without selecting Cube 1, how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's not clear where Cube 1 and Cube 001 are, if you've just selected Cube 001 and entered in Edit mode, you can't select and act on Cube 1

Comment: In object mode, click once to select the front object then click a second time to select the inner one. The selection should toggle between the two each time you click.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.